# What kind of events should be created for a CRUD application?

Tags: events, repository-pattern, crud

I have an application that is centered around a database (ORM is LINQ-SQL) that has a table called Assignment. I am using the repository pattern to manipulate the database. My application is basically going to perform CRUD operations. I am new to delegates and events and I am asking you what events I should create (like maybe AssignmentCreating, AssignmentCreated) and what kind of delegate to use (like maybe a custom delegate or just an EventHandler)? **UPDATE:** My application has a ListView with some columns that show some data. On the right side, I have a panel with textboxes binded to the values of the currently selected assignment. Like a textbox for Score, one for title, etc. and they are all editable. That deals with the *Read* and *Update*. Then I have a custom dialog box that has the same kinds of textboxes, and the dialog *Creates* new assignments. Then users can just select an assignment and *Delete* it via the Delete button, or a context menu.

Comment: Can you talk a bit about in which ways the application will react to the events from the CRUD operations on Assignment?

Comment: Check the update. I talk about my application and the CRUD operations it performs.